# Course for Latent Dirichlet Allocation

Tags: machine-learning, references, natural-language, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

Considering the fact that Andrew Ng played a major role in the development of LDA, I find it surprising that there is no video with him explaining it, similar to his machine learning course.

Is there any good tutorial that explains both the theory and  implementation of LDA like his machine learning courses?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Andrew Ng is indeed one of the co-authors on [the paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/blei03a/blei03a.pdf) that first introduced LDA. David Blei is the first author of that same paper and gave [two fantastic 90-minute lectures](http://videolectures.net/mlss09uk_blei_tm/) on the topic back in 2009. They are more approachable than the actual journal article itself and are worth watching if you want to do anything with LDA.